# Vertex cover of bipartite graph

Tags: algorithms, graphs, approximation, vertex-cover

A vertex cover is a set of vertices such that each edge of the graph is incident to at least one vertex of the set.
A minimum vertex cover is a vertex cover with minimal cardinality.

From [codeforces](https://codeforces.com/blog/entry/63164),

> The minimum vertex cover should contain exactly one vertex for every edge in the maximum matching $M$.  So let's assign a boolean variable for every edge in $M$, say, $x_i = 0$ if the $i$-th edge adds its left end to the vertex cover. One can build all the dependencies over these variables. For example, if there exist edges $(u,v) \in M$ and $(u,w) \notin M$, while $w$ is not saturated by $M$, we have to set $x_i$ equal to 0, because there is no other way to cover the edge $(u, w)$. All the other cases are handled trivially.
>
> As a result, we obtain a full system of restrictions for the set of variables. Finding an arbitrary valid assignment is a classical 2-SAT problem. So we have basically reduced the minimum vertex cover problem to 2-SAT without thinking too much.

I don't understand the variables. I have an edge from maximum matching then I might have both the endpoints of that edge in the vertex cover. But this scheme does not allow this.

This is the graph I have ($2K_2$) two edges in the maximum matching:

[image: 2K_2]

For the first edge I took left vertex in the cover
$x_1=0$ (according to the blog in the link)
for the second edge I took right vertex in the cover $x_2=1$.

Questions:

1. How final 2-sat will be true?
2. Can anyone explain what will be the relation between $x_1$ and $x_2$?

Comment: Vertex cover for bipartite graph is solvable in poly-time by reducing it to perfect matching problem. What I understand from you, is that you try to solve bipartite graph by Linear Programming of vertex cover ("never" ==>"vertices got 0", "always"==> vertices got 1", "neither" ==>"1/2 wight". This LP has only 3 solutions. But if you give a LP a bipartite graph, then in theory it must give you 0/1 solution; since bipartite is not hard problem.

Comment: It depends on the input, you could have multiple minimum vertex cover with the same cost (so each of them could be a solution to the instance) but if they have different cost, then only minimum VC is the solution to the instance. Yes, LP try to classify the bipartite graph instance to output the best solution (the minimum VC) by given 0/1 solution.

Comment: @YOUSEFY, you're missing the point.  That gives you an algorithm to construct *one* minimum vertex cover, but that's not what the question is asking for.  No, a vertex cover is not a solution to the problem listed in the question; the problem listed in the question asks to classify each vertex as N or A or neither.  A single minimum vertex cover does not let you solve that problem.

Comment: That quote already states how to define variables; it says what to define xi to be.  So, I can't tell what you are confused about.  I suggest spending some time working through an example on your own.

Comment: @D.W. Can you give me an example?

Comment: No, that's more work than I want to take on right now.  I suggest you work through one on your own, and then if you get stuck somewhere, show your work so far and the specific part you are unsure of.  You should put in a bunch of effort to try to solve this yourself before asking here, and then use that to help you ask a focused question.

Comment: @D.W. But still, I don't understand the variables. Please a little example.

Comment: @D.W. But still, I don't understand the variables. I have an edge from maximum matching then I can have both the endpoints of that edge in the vertex cover.But this scheme does not allow this.

Comment: For the question to be suitable here, you'll need to figure out how to explain what you do understand and what specifically you don't understand and articulate a specific question about what you don't understand.  Please don't just leave more comments under the question trying to elaborate on your question.  Instead, [edit] your question based on the feedback you've received.

Comment: I don't understand your editing. Why do you add the last paragraph in the other post to this post?

Comment: (1) It looks like you already asked this question at https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/107322/755.  Also, you already about this problem at https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/103534/755 and got an algorithm for it (albeit a slightly different one).  Please don't re-ask your question multiple times; that's not acceptable here.  If your question differs from some existing one, it is your responsibility to explain clearly how this question differs from the previous ones.

Comment: (2) I can't tell what you are asking here.  We are a question-and-answer site, so we require you to ask a specific question in the body of your post.  A question usually ends with a "?".  I don't see any question here.  I only see declarative statements.  That's not suitable here.  Don't force us to guess what your question might be.

Comment: @D.W. look at the edit.

Comment: The question is not clear.  I also removed "Read this blog" as you cannot expect people to read an article to understand your question.  The question should be self-contained.

Comment: It's not self-contained as you have seen the need to add "according to the blog in the link".  Second, this isn't a question anyone can understand: _"How final 2-sat will be true?"_  Please remove the link, remove any unnecessary information, and state your question in a clear and full sentence.

Comment: Comments exist to help you improve your question.  Please don't use them to complain about downvotes or how your question is being received by others.  Everyone is allowed (and encouraged) to vote according to our conscience; that helps us maintain the quality of the site and are critical for the success of the site.  You are not entitled to an answer -- everyone here is a volunteer, and they are free to help or not help as they choose.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As that link explains, you have one variable per edge in the maximum matching, call it $x_i$ for the $i$th edge.  If $x_i=0$, we'll choose the left endpoint of that edge to be in the vertex cover; if $x_i=1$, we'll add the right endpoint of that edge to the vertex cover.

Now, we need to make sure that all of the vertices are covered.  Iterate over each edge $(u,w)$ that's not in the matching:

- If $u$ is touched by the matching but $w$ is not touched by the matching, then the only way to achieve a valid vertex cover from this matching is to include $u$ in the vertex cover.  So, we need to find the edge $(u,v)$ in the matching, then set the corresponding variable $x_i$ to 0 (to ensure $u$ is selected, not $v$).
- If $u$ is not touched by the matching but $w$ is touched, then do the reverse of the above.
- If neither of $u$ nor $w$ is touched by the matching -- this can't happen in a maximum matching (because you could add the edge $(u,w)$ and get a larger matching).  So, you can ignore this case.
- If both $u$ and $w$ are touched by the matching, then we need to ensure that either $u$ or $w$ is selected.  This can be enforced with a 2-CNF clause.  In particular,  let $x_i$ be the variable for the edge that touches $u$, and let $x_j$ be the variable for the edge that touches $w$.  If $u$ is the left endpoint for $x_i$ and $w$ is the right endpoint for $x_j$, we add the 2-CNF clause $\neg x_i \lor x_j$; this ensures that either $u$ or $w$ are selected (or possibly both).

So, combine all the 2-CNF clauses you get in this way, and you get a 2-CNF formula, i.e., a 2-SAT instance. Solving the 2-SAT instance tells you how to pick a set of vertices that will be a vertex cover.  Once you have an assignment that satisfies the 2-SAT instance, that corresponds to a consistent way to choose vertices; and you can verify that this set of vertices forms a vertex cover.

Comment: We can't have two edges from the same vertex in the maximum matching.

Comment: "you have one variable per edge" No,Blog says we have one variable per edge which is in the Maximum matching.

Comment: @ManoharsinhRana, you're right.  See updated answer.

Answer (score 3):

> I don't understand the variables. I have an edge from maximum matching then I might have both the endpoints of that edge in the vertex cover. But this scheme does not allow this.

In bipartite graphs, the size of a maximum matching is also the size of the minimum vertex cover. Since every vertex cover must contain *at least* one vertex from each edge in the matching, it follows that it has to contain *exactly* one vertex from each edge in the matching.

Comment: I'm sure you can figure it out.